Error WBEM_E_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE from ExecMethod
I am trying to create a shadow copy of the C drive using wmivss. When I use the command line with wmic shadowcopy call create Volume='c:\', it successfully creates the shadow copy and returns the following value:
Executing (Win32_ShadowCopy)->create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
        ShadowID = "{85CF0935-84D8-46A4-98DB-43753CA3AD46}";
};

However, when I try to achieve this using C++ code, I encounter an error during the execution of ExecMethod which states ExecMethod failed: WBEM_E_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE(80041014). I am not sure what went wrong in my implementation. I have tried starting my Volume Shadow Copy service, but it didn't help. Here is my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

void Cleanup(IWbemServices* pSvc, IWbemLocator* pLoc) {
    if (pSvc) {
        pSvc->Release();
    }
    if (pLoc) {
        pLoc->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}

HRESULT CreateShadowCopy(IWbemServices* pSvc, BSTR* pShadowID) {
    HRESULT hres;
    IWbemClassObject* pClass = nullptr;
    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = nullptr;
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = nullptr;
    IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = nullptr;

    // Get the class object for Win32_ShadowCopy
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(L"Win32_ShadowCopy", 0, nullptr, &pClass, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"GetObject failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        return hres;
    }

    // Get the method's input parameters
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(L"Create", 0, &pInParamsDefinition, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"GetMethod failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pClass->Release();
        return hres;
    }

    // Create an instance of the input parameters class
    hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"SpawnInstance failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        pClass->Release();
        return hres;
    }

    // Set the input parameters
    VARIANT vtVolume;
    VariantInit(&vtVolume);
    vtVolume.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vtVolume.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"C:\\");

    hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"Volume", 0, &vtVolume, 0);
    VariantClear(&vtVolume);

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"Put failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pClassInstance->Release();
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        pClass->Release();
        return hres;
    }

    // Execute the method
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(L"Win32_ShadowCopy", L"Create", 0, nullptr, pClassInstance, &pOutParams, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"ExecMethod failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pClassInstance->Release();
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        pClass->Release();
        return hres;
    }

    // Get the output parameters
    VARIANT vtShadowID;
    hres = pOutParams->Get(L"ShadowID", 0, &vtShadowID, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"Get ShadowID failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pOutParams->Release();
        pClassInstance->Release();
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        pClass->Release();
        return hres;
    }

    *pShadowID = SysAllocString(vtShadowID.bstrVal);
    VariantClear(&vtShadowID);

    pOutParams->Release();
    pClassInstance->Release();
    pInParamsDefinition->Release();
    pClass->Release();

    return S_OK;
}

int wmain() {
    HRESULT hres;
    IWbemLocator* pLoc = nullptr;
    IWbemServices* pSvc = nullptr;
    BSTR shadowID = nullptr;

    // Step 1: Initialize COM.
    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"CoInitializeEx failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 2: Set general COM security levels.
    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        nullptr,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        nullptr,                    // Authentication services
        nullptr,                    // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,  // Default authentication
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,// Default Impersonation
        nullptr,                    // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                  // Additional capabilities
        nullptr                     // Reserved
    );

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"CoInitializeSecurity failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 3: Obtain the initial locator to WMI.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator,
        (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"CoCreateInstance failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 4: Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        0,
        &pSvc);

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"ConnectServer failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 5: Set security levels on the proxy.
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,
        nullptr,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        nullptr,
        EOAC_NONE);

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"CoSetProxyBlanket failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        Cleanup(pSvc, pLoc);
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 6: Create a shadow copy.
    hres = CreateShadowCopy(pSvc, &shadowID);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::wcerr << L"CreateShadowCopy failed: " << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        Cleanup(pSvc, pLoc);
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 7: Print the shadow copy ID.
    std::wcout << L"Shadow Copy ID: " << shadowID << std::endl;

    // Step 8: Cleanup.
    Cleanup(pSvc, pLoc);
    return 0;
}



I also tried using CreateProcess to create a process to execute wmic shadowcopy call create Volume='c:\'. It produced the same error:
Executing (Win32_ShadowCopy)->create()
ERROR:
Description = Initialization failure

I have no idea why this is happening.
